# Difference between Cybersource Hosted Checkout Notification and Customer Response

Tags: payment-gateway, payment-processing, cybersource

I am a bit confused about the usages of Cyber Source' Hosted Checkout two feature (Admin Web Panel)

- Notifications-> Merchant Notifications
  **(Select and Enter POST URL and/or email address you want the transaction data sent to)**
  VS
- CUSTOMER RESPONSE -> Transaction Response Page
  **(Select the method for hosting the transaction response page, which is displayed at the end of the check-out process.)**

My Questions are :

1. When to use this response from Backend? What is the purpose to separate two responses after a transaction? A use case will be very helpful
2. Should we consider both responses to confirm for a successful Authorization? or if only then which one?
   We already observed, if we override, we immediately receive a response for "**transaction-redirect-response**" but for **transaction-backoffice-response**, we don't receive any response for hostedcheckout.
   Can any body help us here?

Answer (score 0):

they are almost the same, but customer responses are more act like callbacks dedicated to the merchant, a specific merchant URL will be registered on CyberSource, then secure acceptance will look at the URL for redirecting back to the merchant, and the response may include detailed information about the payment status. Notifications (email and URL based) are just to throw a message to the merchant and the payer on behalf of the merchant about the payments, and notifications may not be real-time.